# Setting instance variables in a loop

Tags: java, loops, instance-variables

I am trying to make minesweeper in Java and I created a Box class, with an instance variable isMine which determines whether or not that box is a mine. I use a setter to set this variable, although the problem exists when I use the constructor instead. In my main method when I create and fill the ArrayList containing ArrayLists of Boxes, I also use a random number generator to set the isMine variables. I do this all inside the same loop I use to fill the ArrayLists.

```
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Box>> boxList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Box>>();
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
        boxList.add(new ArrayList<Box>());
    }
    for(int i=0; i<boxList.size(); i++){
        for(int j=0; j<10; j++){
            double rand = Math.random();
            boxList.get(i).add(new Box());
            boxList.get(i).get(j).drawBox(i,j);
            rand = Math.random();
            if(rand>.2){
                boxList.get(i).get(j).setMine(false);
            }
            else{
                boxList.get(i).get(j).setMine(true);
            }
        }
    }
```

However it seems that every Box's isMine is actually set to whatever the last Box's isMine was set to. So if boxList.get(9).get(9).getMine() is false, they will ALL be false.

Comment: I love how you gave us all of the code *except* for the relevant portions (i.e. the entire `Box` class).

Comment: Is your variable isMine static? That would explain a lot...

Comment: The problem does not seem to be in the Box class. The Box class is basically just drawing the box, and a getter and setter for isMine. I do not see how that could create a problem with the setting of specific instancing of isMine

Comment: My variable was static. That fixed it, thank you.

Comment: @EvanS that's a good lesson - the problem is not always where you're looking for it which is why you should post all the relevant code that reproduces the problem.